# Does amazon web services support asp.net 4 and free mysql?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am developing a small web application and thinking of deploying it on amazon web service. I couldn't figure out from their online documents if it's possible to host a .net 4 \ asp.net 4 application, and if it is possible to use a free instance of mysql.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply enough, launching an EC2 instance will give you your own VPS that you can do whatever you want with. If you get a Windows instance, it'll be pretty easy to install .NET, assuming the OS doesn't come with it, and you can install a MySQL server on your instance too.

You might want to look into Amazon's Relational Database Service if you don't want to deal with running a MySQL server, or don't know how.